# $(I-S)$ is invertible

Tags: functional-analysis

> Given $E$ is a Banach space and $S: E \to E$ is a linear continuous function with $\| S \| =c<1$, prove that $(I-S)$ is invertible, that is, $(I-S)^{-1} \in L(E,E)$.

Here $L(E,E)$ denotes the set of linear continuous maps.

I think $\dfrac{I}{I-S}$ is the inverse of $I-S$, but some $x \in E$ such that $Id(x)=S(x)$ so $\dfrac{I}{I-S}$ is not identified and $\dfrac{I}{I-S}$ is not continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(I - S)(I + S + S^2 + S^3 \ldots)  = I$. (Be formal and write this as a limit.) The point is to show that $(I + S + S^2 + \ldots)$ exists in the space of operators. Here is where you use the norm estimate, since you know that $\Sigma c^n$ converges, and you can use this to prove that the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence. Fortunately $L(E,E)$ is complete in the operator norm (exercise?), since $E$ is a Banach space, so you can conclude that  $(I + S + S^2 + \ldots)$ describes an actual operator.

Comment: Never write $\frac{A}{B}$ when $A$ and $B$ are operators or matrices. It's not obvious if it should be interpreted as $AB^{-1}$ or as $B^{-1}A$. Those two expressions can differ in their (matrix) value.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes its a good point, but when $A = I$ it is okay I guess, because left and right inverses are equal. Though it also made me cringe, it is not a good habit for the OP to get into.

Comment: I think $(I−S)(I+S+S2+S3…) \to I$ not equal?

Comment: @NguyễnĐăngKhảiHoàn For example, $(I - S) (I +S) = I - S^2$, $(I - S)(I + S + S^2) = I - S^3$, ... $(I - S)(I + \ldots + S^n) = I - S^n$, and $S^n \to 0$.